# How to use 'doneFileName' property of Camel for file name with double extension?

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I need to route and delete a tar.gz file using apache camel. My file name is filename.tar.gz and trigger file name is filename.trg. So, if I use this uri in from() - "&doneFileName=${file:name.noext}.trg camel routes the file with the Trigger file name - filename.tar.trg. But I need the doneFileName as filename.trg.

How can I achieve this?? I tried to nest the ${file:name.noext} but seems not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah its in fact a bug in Apache Camel. I have logged a ticket to get it to support file extensions having double dots

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8484

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to use something like this -
doneFileName=${bean:<BeanId>.<MethodName>(${file:name.noext})}

to write a custom bean method to get the exact fileName??

Comment: No the docs says - http://camel.apache.org/file2:  Currently Camel supports the following two dynamic tokens: file:name and file:name.noext which must be enclosed in ${ }. The consumer only supports the static part of the done file name as either prefix or suffix (not both).

Comment: HI, 
In a single route expression e.g. - from().to() Can I use the doneFileName property enabled selectively for some specific files?? e.g. - If I need to route File1.tar.gz and File2.txt then is it possible that Camel will route the file File1.tar.gz when File1.trg is present but it will not depend on File2.trg while routing ??